# What is correct 'Build Action' setting for Global.asax of a WCF Service?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio, global-asax

I have a Global.asax file that is part of a WCF Service provect.

What is correct **'Build Action'** *setting* for **Global.asax** for the deployment?

(So that it is consumed properly)

For example: ApplicationDefinition? -with Copy Always?

Answer (score 1):

On our application we have its *Build Action* set to `Content` and the *Copy to Output Dir* setting set to `Do not copy` with no issues.

Comment: Is it WCF implemented as RESTFul Service?

Comment: No its hosting WCF soap services (under IIS).